# Getting "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer" when trying to extract number from string

Tags: ruby, regex, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I'm having an issue extracting the numeric portion of a field and inserting it into my model attribute.  I have

```
  puts "age:#{age}"
  self.age = age[/\d+/].present? ? age[/\d+/].to_i : nil
```

But I'm getting the output

```
age:41
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/models/my_object_time.rb:129:in `[]'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/models/my_object_time.rb:129:in `set_age'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/models/my_object_time.rb:51:in `block in <class:RaceTime>'
```

Is there a better way to write the above to extract the number (if ther eis one) but also avoid the error I'm seeing?

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean?

Comment: Oh you're a newbie, huh?  In your console enter, 'str = "123"' and then enter "str[/\d+/]".  Behold your strange language!

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that the `[]` you are calling expects an [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) as an argument, and thus it tries to convert the [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) to an `Integer` (by calling [`to_int`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-to_int)) but fails because `Regexp`s don't respond to `to_int`.

Since [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) *does* take a `Regexp` as an argument, it's obvious that the object referenced by `age` cannot be a [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html), it must be something else. Unfortunately, you don't tell us *what* object it is (you really should include such information in your question!) but we can make an educated guess: there are only three `[]` methods in Ruby I can think of, which would conceivably raise this exact error: [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D), [`MatchData#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D), and [`Integer#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D). So, my best guess at this point is that your `age` object is actually not a `String`, but rather a [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/MatchData.html) object, an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html), or an [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html).

But, we can do better: you included the result of [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) in your question. [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_s) returns something like `'[1, 2, 3]'`, but your question shows that `age.to_s` returns something like `'41'`. So, it can't be an `Array`.

Ergo, `age` is either a `MatchData` object or an `Integer`, but you are expecting it to be a `String`. You need to figure out where `age` is coming from, and why it isn't what you expect it to be, then fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `age` variable is probably a number. I get the same error when I try to use the `[/regex/]` method with a number:

```
[5] pry(main)> 1[//]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer
```

You could say `age = age.to_s` first

Comment: If `age` is indeed a number, then it makes no sense to convert it to a string first to then extract the number, only to parse it into a number, which is going to be the very number you started out to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better write that like:

```
str = "sometext 123 sometext"
self.age = /(?<age>\d+)/ =~ str.to_s ? age.to_i : nil
```